# Automatic send pm telegram robot

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm C# developer.

I want make a Telegram robot that send pm to another robot in specific times.
If there is similar robot please call me the name.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, bot **CAN NOT** conversation with other bot at this time.

But you can try unofficial Telegram command line tool called [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg), this allows you send messages as a user without GUI.